# Apache Error 500 without log info when trying to access to a php5.3 website

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

I've the next problem. I had to do some rewriteUrl-work  for a website... Well, in fact, I had to modify **the already working urlRewriting**. Being cautious, I saved a copy of the whole source code, even the .htaccess file, just in case...

Well, I introduce some minor changes to the .htaccess (I changed a line) that don't seem to work. Showing a blank page... I undo these changes and... I still get the same blank page. Replacing the .htaccess file with the saved version doesn't work either.

I neither can access to phpMyAdmin... getting a Error 500. But no error is shown at error.log or acces.log. I've modified the index.php file and added an echo "echo" line at the beginning of the file that is actually shown... So I have an error while doing the include/require stuff..

```
<?php


echo "echo";

require_once('./conf/conf.main.php');
include_once(INC_PATH.'inc.common.php');
require_once 'jtpl_standalone_prepend.php';
require_once(CLASS_PATH.'class.distri.php');
require_once(CLASS_PATH.'class.news.php');
require_once(CLASS_PATH.'class.xmltoarray.php');
require_once(CLASS_PATH.'class.grossistes.php');

 echo "echo";
```

The 2nd 'echo' isn't shown. I'm working with:

- PHP: 5.3.3
- Apache: 2.2.16
- MySQL: 5.1

  It's very strange, because I've the same .htaccess that worked before,... Any ideas?

  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the request is passed on to PHP, it is responsible for handling and logging the 500 error.

Examine your PHP error log for details; if you don't know where this is, look in your php.ini.